# When an installation fails

Tags: ssms, failed-installation, sql-server-data-tools

So, an installation of mine failed (SQL Server Data Tools 2015) and then, there was a restart that was triggered and my installation was cancelled out before I was able to finish it.  when I try running the installation it asks me to repair or uninstall.

I am just curious how exactly repair works behind the scenes.  Will it verify that things are missing and install the things that haven't been installed at this point?

Or should I uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question: I believe that Repair did the job just fine in verifying content and replacing missing content. I will update this post if anything changes in the future during my use.